# Protractor control flow and non-asynchronous tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm very new to angular and protractor, but I'm having to write the e2e tests for a very complex app and I'm struggling to get to grips with promises and the control flow.

I've read the documentation and it seems straight forward, and for simple tests it is.  However some of the steps I need require quite a lot of work in the page object file, executing several synchronous functions to get to the outcome I need, and this is causing a huge headache.  Even using

```
var deferred = protractor.promise.defer()
deferred.fulfill()
return deferred.promise
```

In the tests and chaining them with then's they run in a bizarre order.  I've tried manipulating the control flow and I'm still getting weird results, but if I have logical steps in the spec and an assertion at the end, and the logical steps do a really simple thing ie

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
    var angularHomepage = new AngularHomepage();
    angularHomepage.get();

    angularHomepage.setName('Julie');

    expect(angularHomepage.getGreeting()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });
});
```

It works fine, so my question is, does the control flow only apply to the spec file?  would I have to do all of my chaining there instead of the page object?  or is there a good way to run a function, that calls several other functions in a page object, to return a value and make sure that returns from one are being passed into the subsequent function?  for example

```
this.someFunction = function(var) {
  var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

  self.function1(var).then(function(var2) {
    self.function2(var2).then(function(var3) {
      deferred.fulfill(var3)
    });
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

In the page object and something like this in the spec

```
describe('some test', function() {
      it('should do something', function() {            
        expect(pageObject.someFunction()).toEqual('A value.');
      });
});
```

If that makes any sense at all?

Thanks.